# What does it mean to say that "the where clause of select statements can perform >, >=, <, <= operations on one column only"?

Tags: sql, database, google-app-engine, where-clause

According to [the Wikipedia article on Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine):

> The where clause of select statements
>   can perform >, >=, <, <= operations on
>   one column only. Therefore, only
>   simple where clauses can be
>   constructed.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this document](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Restrictions_on_Queries):

For example, this query is allowed:

```
select from Person where birthYear >= minBirthYearParam
                      && birthYear <= maxBirthYearParam
```

However, this query is not allowed, because it uses inequality filters on two different properties in the same query:

```
select from Person where birthYear >= minBirthYearParam
                      && height >= minHeightParam   // ERROR
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you can't compare two columns to each other: `WHERE Column1 > Column2` wouldn't work for example.

Comment: Yes, You can't do that but the problem is answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461444/what-does-it-mean-to-say-that-the-where-clause-of-select-statements-can-perform/1461483#1461483

Answer (score 1):

Google explains it in their [article](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Introducing_Queries) on querying the App Engine datastore.  Look for the bulleted list titled, "The filter operator can be any of the following:"